# Memory consumption onto server using php

Tags: php

In my application i often encounter with this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 52944 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\index.php on line 337
```

so far i am working on localhost and encountered with memory error what when i deployed my application on to server where many user perform same operation at a time.

i just want to ask how can i check what are the resources that is in the memory

and is on to the server each user get a separate memory are all user use 128 Mb of memory that i used in my localhost

Comment: You probably assigned many variables, used a lot of recursion, etc ... There are many ways this can happen, and a meaningful answer if difficult to give ... Perhaps you can post some of your code?

Comment: 128 Mb is memory used by your script . i.e. all users who are executing the script, the script is consuming 128 Mb of memory

Answer (score 1):

You can check RAM usage with this function:

```
function getRamUsage($size) {
    $unit = array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}
```

Example:

`$ramUsage = getRamUsage(memory_get_usage(true));`

Anyway, IMHO your code needs to be reviewed and/or rewritten. Please post some code, what is happening in your index.php on line 337 ?

Answer (score 0):

Locally turn error_reporting to E_ALL see if anything is being outputted, as you may have error messaging suppressed on your server but it still may be buffering this to a file or database table if you have this set up, this can exhaust memory and the speed of your app